# AngularFire - Firestore - Check if a document exists whilst performing queries

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I've seen examples of how to check if a specific document exists. However, is it possible to check if documents exist whilst performing a query like the following?

```
private albumsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
albums: Observable<any[]>;

...


this.albumCollection = this.afs.collection<any>(`albums`, ref => {
  return ref.where('albumid', "==", this.albumid);
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you could do something along the lines of this:

```
this.afs.collection(`albums`, ref => ref.where('albumid', "==", this.albumid)).snapshotChanges().subscribe(res => {
    if (res.length > 0)
    {
    console.log("Match found.");
    }
    else
    {
    console.log("Does not exist.");
    }
});
```

If the array of snapshots isn't empty then you have albums that match the ID you are querying for. Then by using snapshotChanges you could get the key of each document and their values.